# Accessing the enclosing viewmodel when using FluentValidation on an inner viewmodel

Tags: c#, validation, fluentvalidation

Suppose I have 2 view models, Project and Task. The Project contains a List of Tasks. The Project has a BeginDate and an EndDate. The Tasks also each have a BeginDate and an EndDate.

## Project class

```
public class Project
{
  public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
  public List<Task> Tasks { get; set; }
}
```

## Task class

```
public class Task
{
  public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
  public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use FluentValidation to verify that each date in a Task falls within the dates of the Project. I can do that like this:

## ProjectValidator class

```
public class ProjectValidator : AbstractValidator<Project>
{
  public ProjectValidator()
  {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Tasks)
      .Must(((p, t) => t.BeginDate >= p.BeginDate && t.BeginDate <= p.EndDate))
      .WithMessage("Task Begin Date must be within Project's Begin and End Dates.");

    RuleForEach(x => x.Tasks)
      .Must(((p, t) => t.EndDate >= p.BeginDate && t.EndDate <= p.EndDate))
      .WithMessage("Task End Date must be within Project's Begin and End Dates.");
  }
}
```

However, this does not flag the particular Task Begin or End Date that is the problem. The error message is displayed at the top of the screen in the error summary, not next to the problem date. There can be a dozen or more dates to examine, making it hard to figure out which one is actually the problem.

Presumably this is because I am validating at the Project level rather than the individual Task level. To get fields within the Task flagged with error messages, I need to validate the Task.

So I need to write a TaskValidator, something like this:

## TaskValidator class

```
public class TaskValidator : AbstractValidator<Task>
{
  Project _proj;

  public TaskValidator(Project proj)
  {
    _proj = proj;

    RuleFor(x => x.BeginDate)
      .Must(BeWithinProjectDates)
      .WithMessage("Task Begin Date must be within Project's Begin and End Dates.");

    RuleFor(x => x.EndDate)
      .Must(BeWithinProjectDates)
      .WithMessage("Task End Date must be within Project's Begin and End Dates.");
  }

  private bool BeWithinProjectDates(DateTime date)
  {
    return (date >= _proj.BeginDate &&
            date <= _proj.EndDate);
  }
}
```

I then can pass the Project viewmodel to the TaskValidator in a rule, like this:

## ProjectValidator class (modified)

```
public class ProjectValidator : AbstractValidator<Project>
{
  public ProjectValidator()
  {
    RuleForEach(x => x.Tasks)
      .SetValidator(x => new TaskValidator(x));
  }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. The TaskValidator constructor is called once, to initialize the validator. It isn't called at the time the validation happens. This means that the Project object is empty.

Is there any way I can reference the Project viewmodel from within the TaskValidator, so that I can access the values of the Project Begin Date and End Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Jeremy Skinner, the author of FluentValidation, I was able to get this working!

First, the SetValidator parameter **must** be a lambda expression. That will cause it to be called at the appropriate time. I actually was already doing this, although I mistakenly left it off when posting my question.

Secondly, I'm using SimpleInjector and a validator factory to implement Dependency Injection. That means that I must either **not register** the TaskValidator or ensure that the factory doesn't return one.

## ValidatorFactory

```
public class ValidatorFactory : ValidatorFactoryBase
{
    private readonly Container _container;

    public ValidatorFactory(Container container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    public override IValidator CreateInstance(Type validatorType)
    {
        if (_container.GetRegistration(validatorType) == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        if (validatorType == typeof(IValidator<Task>))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return (IValidator)_container.GetInstance(validatorType);
    }
}
```

That will ensure that the lambda expression in the SetValidator call creates the TaskValidator directly, rather than via the validator factory.

Answer (score 0):

I undestand correctly you are doing something like this

```
 RuleForEach(p => p.Tasks).SetValidator(project => new TaskValidator(project));
```

and it doesn't work?
Why don't you just add Project property into your Task ViewModel?

```
public class Task
{
    public DateTime BeginDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

    public Project Project { get; set; }
}
```

It's not difficult to set this property when you create you ViewModels.

Comment: I could add the Project view model into the Task view model, but the Project is being entered at the same time as the Tasks (i.e. it's a new Project, so the user enters the Project dates and then enters server Tasks with their dates on the same screen). Although the "outer" Project view model would contain the user's input when they click the submit button, the "inner" Project view models would not have that information when the validation occurs. (I suppose I could do a bunch of JavaScript copying into hidden fields on submit, but I want to avoid that.)